# Android resource linking failed error: failed linking references. Drawables

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I notice all my drawables files can not be linked after i launch android from where i stop work the previous day:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:24: error: resource drawable/slide (aka com.accessng.devotion:drawable/slide) not found.
C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_read.xml:31: error: resource drawable/image (aka com.accessng.devotion:drawable/image) not found.
C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\src\main\res\layout\main_menu_item.xml:15: error: resource drawable/menu_bg (aka com.accessng.devotion:drawable/menu_bg) not found.
C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\src\main\res\layout\read_setting_bottom_sheet.xml:94: error: resource drawable/ic_night (aka com.accessng.devotion:drawable/ic_night) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Command: C:\Users\Access\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\b88544288ad13e2c86f99a94f775848a\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Access\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\build\intermediates\instant_run_merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.accessng.devotion\
        -0\
        apk\
        --preferred-density\
        xhdpi\
        --output-text-symbols\
        C:\Users\Access\AndroidStudioProjects\Devotion\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: check if the files exists in the directory. Also try invalidating your caches and restart File>Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Done that no solution yet

Comment: also check if the files are in any other drawable folder like hdpi,xhdpi,v24 like that.

Comment: Update your compile SDK to 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all comments i added a vector asset file in drawable like the IDE crashed while adding the file and the content of the xml was empty. once i deleted the file all worked well. but the error log never mentioned that file